# Atomically get value on Mac OS

Tags: function, macos, get, atomic, darwin

I need some function to atomically get int value. Something called OSAtomicGet(). Analog of g_atomic_int_get().

Comment: Сounterquestion: where all the int values are stored so that you can access them with OSAtomic* API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereferencing an `int` from a known pointer is always atomic on architectures running Mac/iStuffs. Use [OSMemoryBarrier()](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/OSMemoryBarrier.3.html) if you need a memory barrier.

```
int OSAtomicGet(volatile int* value) {
   OSMemoryBarrier();
   return *value;
}
```